Apache2 processes HTTPS on 80 not 443
Thats my site config for apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect permanent / https://example.net

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

    #DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress

    <Directory /srv/www/wordpress>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /srv/www/wordpress/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate


</VirtualHost>


But still, the browser is stuck in a redirection loop, since all traffic, HTTP or HTTPS gets processed by port 80. My domain uses Cloudflare Nameservers
I have to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS because wordpress has a mixed content error and tries to fetch some files over http rather than https, which gives errors. Better Search Replace does not work.
I dont see any error in my configuration file, are there other configs, that i can try to let apache process HTTPS traffic only with the 443 virtual host?

have you add Listen 443 ?

i havent, i just added it but not the site isnt accessible at all.
Cloudflare: Web server is down Error code 521
